# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Vignette Mask

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am on Android API Level 9. I have a Camera preview loaded into a SurfaceView. I am trying to  draw a vignette mask over this. In order to do so I am using a GLSurfaceView. I prepared a mask in XCode shader builder using the following fragment shader code (or is it a pixel shader?) which compiles successfully so far:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{ 
float innerAlpha = 0.0;
float outerAlpha = 1.0;
float len = 1.7;
float startAdjustment = -0.2;
float diff = 0.4;
float alphaStep = outerAlpha / len;
vec2 center = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
vec2 foc1 = vec2(diff,0.);
vec2 foc2 = vec2(-diff,0.);
float r = distance(center+foc1,gl_TexCoord[0].xy) + distance(center+foc2,gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
float alpha = r  - (diff * 2.0) * alphaStep - startAdjustment;
vec4 vColor = vec4(0.,0.,0., innerAlpha + alpha);
gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

However, I do not know how to implement this into code for Android. Basically I think I would need to create a rectangle, which would cover the whole view and apply this kind of code generated texture on it. I just can not manage to figure out the actual code. Ideally, it should be in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Edit1:

@Tim - I tried to follow the tutorials here http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html 
and here 
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/ 
and I basically understand, how to draw a triangle. But I do not understand, how to draw rectangle - I mean do I really need to draw two triangles actually or can I just define rectangle (or other complex shapes) right away? 
As for the textures - in all tutorials I have seen, textures are actually being loaded from image files, but I would be interested in knowing, how can I actually kind of generate one using the pixel shader above.

Comment: Have you tried following any tutorials, or do you have any OpenGL experience? I think that "How do I draw in OpenGL" might be a bit beyond the scope of a single question. Or can you show what you have tried, if you think you might be close?

Comment: *do I really need to draw two triangles actually or can I just define rectangle*  Yes, you need to draw two triangles if you want a quad. It sounds like you're trying to do too much too quickly. Just concentrate on drawing a plain colored quad, and you can add things in incremental steps once you've understood the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have found the answer, how to draw the oval shaped mask.

Actually, the problem was, that I was thinking of gl_FragCoord in the range of 0.0 to 1.0,
but they have to be specified in actual pixels instead, e.g. 600.0 x 900.0 etc.

With little tweaks (changing vec2's to floats) I have been able to draw nice oval shaped mask over the whole screen in OpenGL. Here is the final fragment shader. Note, that you must specify the uniforms before drawing. If you are gonna try this, make sure to keep uSlope to somewhere between 0.1 and 2.0 to get meaningful results. Also, please, note that uInnerAlpha has to be lower than uOuterAlpha with this particular piece of code. For a typical vignette,
uInnerAlpha is 0.0 and uOuterAlpha is 1.0.

```
precision mediump float;

uniform float uWidth;
uniform float uHeight;
uniform float uSlope;
uniform float uStartAdjustment;
uniform float uEllipseLength;
uniform float uInnerAlpha;
uniform float uOuterAlpha;

void main() {

float gradientLength = uHeight * uSlope;
float alphaStep = uOuterAlpha / gradientLength;
float x1 = (uWidth / 2.0);
float y1 = (uHeight / 2.0) - uEllipseLength;
float x2 = (uWidth / 2.0);
float y2 = (uHeight / 2.0) + uEllipseLength;

float dist1 = sqrt(pow(abs(gl_FragCoord.x - x1), 2.0) + pow(abs(gl_FragCoord.y - y1), 2.0));
float dist2 = sqrt(pow(abs(gl_FragCoord.x - x2), 2.0) + pow(abs(gl_FragCoord.y - y2), 2.0));
float dist = (dist1 + dist2);

float alpha = ((dist - (uEllipseLength * 2.0)) * alphaStep - uStartAdjustment) + uInnerAlpha;
if (alpha > uOuterAlpha) {
    alpha = uOuterAlpha;
}
if (alpha < uInnerAlpha) {
    alpha = uInnerAlpha;
}

vec4 newColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);

gl_FragColor = newColor;

}
```